# Has anyone heard of the EDM genre "Trance Ragecore"?

Tags: electronic-music, metal, trap

Its a mix between trance and Trap Metal but has darkpsy elements in it I was wondering if anyone's heard of it its fairly new and I was wondering if someone could find some Trance Ragecore Tracks and tell me their names and by what DJs made them, it doesn't need to be actual songs but just names of the makers of the songs, thanks.

I heard of it from a friend in early march this year and am starting to like the more darker world of electronic music

Comment: This may help you https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/has-anyone-heard-of-the-edm-genre-trance-ragecore

Answer (score 1):

via [reddit trapmetal](https://www.reddit.com/r/trapmetal/comments/apins5/ragecore_trap_metal/)  , [this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ozv7gatDW4o&feature=youtu.be) names a number of artists : for example [Prxjek](https://soundcloud.com/prxjek)
.

[Another compilation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4jAdvcOsTM), with names.

sounds as if the definition of "ragecore" is still fluid, or subject to some overlap with other similar genres.

Answer (score 1):

Also according to Wikipedia

> Trance Ragecore unlike other forms of trance which prefer the
>   classical vibe,"Trance Ragecore" is a new form of trance involving the
>   extended electrical feel of faster trance and Darkpsy Psytrance mixed
>   with the goth rap of Rap Metal and has baroque, Techno and Acid House
>   elements in it to create a very frightening sound called Trance
>   Ragecore

There used to be a hyperlink to the actual page but it appears to be dead now

But this was copied from the link below

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trance_genres